# jquery google app engine

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine

I have an issue where the Javascript file that I have uploaded does not work. My code is below.

app.yaml has:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: /js
```

index.html has:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js has:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img').click(function(){
       $(this).fadeOut('slow');
   });
   $('p').click(function(){
       $(this).fadeOut('slow');
   });
   alert("hi");
});
```

and not even the alert comes out

Comment: are you importing jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import jquery. Try this fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  });
  $('p').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  });
  alert("hi");
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools.png"/>
<p>Click Me</p>
```

Comment: you welcome!!! happy to see it´s working!!!. Remember!!! Be careful when jQuery loads. Always use $(document).ready, as it starts at the moment everything has loaded!!

Answer (score -1):

I think your  `src="/js/script.js"` its not correct try with:

```
 src="js/script.js"
```